# Arduino Vibrate Sensor Logs to Web Panel

Tags: javascript, php, arduino-uno

I've use this tutorial to connect my Arduino Uno with Vibrate Sensor

[Using this Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SUgfuUDYNk)

Vibrate levels showing succssfully in my serial monitor ,

my question is it possible to take those values into PHP base web page ?

I need to show those data logs as a real time chart (JavaScript possibly ) .

Comment: Maybe adding some would help the others to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible, but you will need Ethernet or Wi-fi module, to connect to local lan.
Maybe this will help you - http://www.icreateproject.info/uncategorized/arduino-display-data-over-local-network/

Comment: Thank you it was really helpful , however I used C# console application to feed data into database.